# Is it possible to change/restrict values of dynamicfilter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

I need to restrict the values that are available in a DynamicFilter control for a gridview.

The table that is being filtered will only show values that are available to the currently logged in user based on a where clause. I want the filter controls to use the same where clause

I am using dynamic data for this project.

Is this possible or should I use my own filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to use the QueryExtender class to filer you data. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryextender(VS.100).aspx

Regards
--Jocke